# Add delegate to CalloutView

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am currently using the `MapBox` swift library and I am trying to add a delegate to the callout view.

I am trying to do it like this :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, calloutViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLCalloutView? {
    let callout = TabletMapSearchCalloutView(representedObject: annotation, mapView: mapView)
    callout.delegate = self
    return callout
}
```

But it seems that there is an internal worker that runs in the library that sets the delegate after this method to the `MGLMapView`.

So my question is, how do I go about adding a delegate to the callout so that I can access the tapped event?

Comment: is the delegate object is your custom defined object?

Comment: Show your `TabletMapSearchCalloutView` code.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the `MGLMapViewDelegate` has the method that I was looking for

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation)
```